# Set the machine Name with inno-setup

Tags: inno-setup

How can I Get & Set the machine name in may configuration INI

Is there any key or function in inno-Setup to get the machine name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `{computername}` constant. This can then be used as the value in your [Ini] section entry.

Comment: (Which is easily available in the help file)

Answer (score 0):

You will need this:

`function SetComputerName(lpComputerName: PAnsiChar): BOOL;
    external 'SetComputerNameA@kernel32.dll stdcall';`

And then call this from one of your functions:

`SetComputerName(YOURNEWHOSTNAME)`

Hope this helps 6 Years later LOL

Comment: I think the question is about *"setting machine name in configuration INI file"*, not about setting an actual computer name. That's covered in [Changing the computer name with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33944319/850848). Where I actually assume you have taken the code from, as it's noticeably identical.