# Changing the computer name with Inno Setup

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, computer-name

Is there a way to change your computer name with Inno Setup? I'm new to Inno Setup but I searched quite alot and I haven't found any example of it. I know you can access the computer name with the constant `{computername}`, but it seems like there is no function to change it.

I thought about changing the registry key of the computer name in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName` with section `[Registry]`, but I don't know what will happen if I use the syntax to create a new key. Will it overwrite it? Will it throw me an error? Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Example of syntax for creating a new key**

```
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "ComputerName"; ValueData: "MyNewComputerName";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call [`SetComputerName` API function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-setcomputernamea).

Also as the computer name change is valid only after the computer restarts, you should set [`AlwaysRestart` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_alwaysrestart) to `yes` to make the installer restart the computer after the installation.

```pascal
[Setup]
AlwaysRestart=yes

[Code]

function SetComputerName(lpComputerName: PAnsiChar): BOOL;
    external 'SetComputerNameA@kernel32.dll stdcall';

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    Log('Changing computer name');
    if SetComputerName('MyNewName') then
    begin
      Log('Computer name changed');
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Failed to change computer name - ' + SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Tested on *Unicode* version of Inno Setup (the only version as of Inno Setup 6).

---

Changing registry key might work too. Just you should use `ComputerName` key (not `ActiveComputerName`) and restart.

I believe your syntax is correct otherwise. Though I didn't test it. However note that [maximal computer name length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/computer-names) is 15 characters (so `MyNewComputerName` is too long).

Comment: Nice answer! However there is something wierd, the code is supose to be Pascal, doesn't it? Why the link you put is in c++? I'm probably doing bad assumption thought.

Comment: Do you mean the reference to `SetComputerName`? Well native API declaration are usually given/documented in C. That does not mean that you cannot call the function from Pascal. You just need to convert the C declaration to Pascal. That's what the `function SetComputerName ... external` is good for.

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you for the explanation!